# REST API, serving variants of a representation. Exporting files with dependencies

Tags: api, rest, content-negotiation

I have a question about best practices around serving varying representations of an resource. My use case is a bit more complex than simply serving representations of the object in different content types (Say xml or json).

Background: This API is for a content management system. One crucial aspect of the API is that a user can request a zip file of a document, as well as all of its dependencies (Linked images, and other documents).

For instance, one might access a document at `/rest/all-documents/{doc-id}` which would return  the XML representation of the document.

When designing a way for them to get a zip of the document and all it's dependencies, I have come up with a few options:

1. Use content negotiation and set the `Accept` header to something vendor specific, ie: vnd.company.compiled-doc+zip
2. Use a sub collection such as `/rest/all-documents/{doc-id}/export` (Export is a verb, so I am not sure if this is well standardized)
3. Provide a service at a different URI which was read only: `/rest/compiled-documents/{doc-id}`

As this problem is likely to come up again and again I am having a really hard time determining what is going to be best way to design this part of the API. So far I am leaning towards option 3,

Thanks,

Casey

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following approach : /rest/all-documents/{doc-id}.zip

It would be interesting to know what solution you finally chosed.

Vince.